# Is it bad practice to query two different databases on one page?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysql

I'm working with a programmer who doesn't want me touching his database...

I would like work with a database instead of hard coding my content but don't want the sites performance to suffer.

Is it bad practice to query two different databases on one page?

If its not a problem is there a limit to how many databases you can query per page?

PS the site is php/mysql

Comment: Can you probably tell us more about the project architecture and role division? What's yours?

Comment: is it his database or the projects?

Comment: Was originally his project. Now it is my project but is still under his hosting so he controls the back end so far.

Answer (score 5):

> me touching his database

That's probably because there is a layered architecture in place and you're not supposed to be talking to the database directly.

Otherwise, if you've come already to the division - "my" database, "his" markup, it's a recipe for disaster.

> Is it bad practice to query two different databases on one page?

No, if there is a real need to do it. Yes, if only because somebody declared the database their property and you've got to have your own.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a "my database" "his markup" scenario. 
Darn politics.

Answer (score 1):

No its not a problem, in some scenarios it's even a pretty good approach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if the databases are holding related data. If they are related, it makes sense to keep them in once database. The programmer could then give you a user account with limited access so that you can't corrupt other things.

There is some cost to making a new connection, but it will likely be negligible if you are doing a number of queries.

Comment: I don't know how his db is structured but i guess ill be working on my own if its not a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a separate schema in his DB? If so, then you could save some connection building /destruction time.

Will you be storing data/relational data in the DB?  If not, can you get away with include("file.php")

All that being said it's not a bad practice to have multiple DBs on a page you just need a good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

i routinely hit a estimate database and a reference database aka customer live in texas, closest office is 150 miles away.